# How to Export the SSL Cert expiration deatils to Excel sheet using Powershell script

Tags: powershell

I have written a code where in it will export all the SSL cert details to an excel sheet using the Powershell script, but in the output windows i need the details including the Server name as below:

**Code**

````
$deadline = (Get-Date).AddDays($threshold)   #Set deadline date 

Invoke-Command -ComputerName AAA, BBB { Dir Cert:\LocalMachine\My } | foreach { 
  If ($_.NotAfter -le $deadline) { $_ | Select Issuer, Subject, ServerName, NotAfter, @{Label="Expires In (Days)";Expression={($_.NotAfter - (Get-Date)).Days}} } 
} | Export-Csv -Path C:\users\$env:username\desktop\Multiplecert_results.csv -NoTypeInformation -Force```

**Output**
*Issuer            : CN=MS-Organization-P2P-Access [2019]
Subject           : CN=742833b2-8a94-400a-8bbc-ded50dfd3f1a, 
                    DC=8d894c2b-238f-490b-8dd1-d93898c5bf83
ServerName        : 
NotAfter          : 1/21/2020 10:03:43 PM
Expires In (Days) : 0*

I need the Server name details in the above output when i run the Script which i wrote.

Thanks in Advance.
````

Answer (score 0):

Just use the $env:COMPUTERNAME in your code. No need for that loop either as you can do that in the Invoke. You can simplify this by just doing this...

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'aaa', 'bbb' { 
    Get-ChildItem -Path 'Cert:\LocalMachine\My' | 
    Select-Object -Property Issuer, Subject, 
}

# Results
Issuer         : ...
Subject        : ...
PSComputerName : ...
RunspaceId     : ...
```

Sticking that $env in will get you the name twice

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'aaa', 'bbb' { 
    Get-ChildItem -Path 'Cert:\LocalMachine\My' | 
    Select-Object -Property Issuer, Subject, 
    @{Label = 'ServerName';Expression = {$env:COMPUTERNAME}}
}

# Results
Issuer         : ...
Subject        : ...
ServerName     : ...
PSComputerName : ...
RunspaceId     : ...
```

As for this...

> "I tried in this way but the code doesn't work,"

What does this mean, as you are not saying / showing what is not working?

```
$threshold = 300 #Number of days to look for expiring certificates 
$deadline = (Get-Date).AddDays($threshold) #Set deadline date
```

***Again, don't do this...***

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'AAA', 'BBB' | 
foreach { 
Get-ChildItem -Path 'Cert:\LocalMachine\My' | 
    Select-Object -Property Issuer, Subject 
    @{Label = 'ServerName';Expression = {$env:COMPUTERNAME}}, 
    @{Label='Expires In (Days)';Expression = {($_.NotAfter - (Get-Date)).Days}} 
}
```

... because you are asking for data (that ForEach) outside of the call to the remote server.

***Do this...***

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'aaa', 'bbb' { 
    Get-ChildItem -Path 'Cert:\LocalMachine\My' | 
    Select-Object -Property Issuer, Subject 
    @{Label = 'ServerName';Expression = {$env:COMPUTERNAME}}, 
    @{Label='Expires In (Days)';Expression = {($_.NotAfter - (Get-Date)).Days}} 
}
```

As for...

> One last doubt in my script I have a label to get the Expiry in Days,
> how can I include that in your Script to get the Expiration days

... the certificate expiration this is a common and well-documented thing for years now. You are using the wrong operator in that expiration section.

See this article:
[Use PowerShell to Find Certificates that are About to Expire](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-find-certificates-that-are-about-to-expire)

```
Get-ChildItem -Path cert: -Recurse -ExpiringInDays 75
```

Or

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | 
where { $_.notafter -le (get-date).AddDays(75) } | 
select thumbprint, subject
```

***So, your code is this***

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'aaa', 'bbb' { 
    Get-ChildItem -Path 'Cert:\LocalMachine\My' | 
    Select-Object -Property Issuer, Subject 
    @{Label = 'ServerName';Expression = {$env:COMPUTERNAME}}, 
    @{Label='Expires In (Days)';Expression = {$_.notafter -le (get-date).AddDays($threshold)}} 
}
```

As for this...

> When i tried the above script which you suggested for the Expiry In
> days one

... try it this way.

```
Clear-Host

Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'aaa', 'bbb' { 
    Get-ChildItem -Path 'Cert:\LocalMachine\My' -Recurse | 
    Select-Object -Property Issuer, Subject, NotAfter, 
    @{Label = 'ServerName';Expression = {$env:COMPUTERNAME}}, 
    @{Label='Expires In (Days)';Expression = {(New-TimeSpan -Start (Get-Date) -End $PSitem.NotAfter).Days}} 
}

# Results

...

Issuer            : CN=M...
Subject           : CN=M...
NotAfter          : 5/9/2021 7:28:13 PM
ServerName        : aaa
Expires In (Days) : 474
PSComputerName    : aaa
RunspaceId        : 9...

Issuer            : CN=Th...
Subject           : CN=Th...
NotAfter          : 12/31/2020 6:59:59 PM
ServerName        : aaa
Expires In (Days) : 344
PSComputerName    : aaa
RunspaceId        : 9...
...
```

Comment: But when i use multiple servers in Invoke command i am getting the server name in the label from where i run the script, not the server name accordingly

Comment: Again, that is because you are asking for the info after the remote command, that Invoke is done. That is why I placed the call to the data in the Invoke directly. If you use the sample I have in my response, you should get the server name in each pass. Again, no need for that external loop, that Invoke, because of the server list is an implicit loop. I did this call in one of my labs, so, I know it returns the corect names and other values. Do, this to see what I mean - Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'aaa', 'bbb' { $env:COMPUTERNAME }

Comment: Thanks for the Clear explanation, i got the output as expected.

Comment: One last doubt in my script i have a label to get the Expiry in Days, how can i include that in your Script to get the Expiration days.

Comment: The same way you are doing it in your loop. Take everything in the ForEach and move it inside the Invoke and add there whatever else you need. Again, that FoREach is not really needed.

Comment: I tried in this way but the code doesn't work, can you please help me,
`$threshold = 300   #Number of days to look for expiring certificates 
 
$deadline = (Get-Date).AddDays($threshold)   #Set deadline date 


Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'AAA', 'BBB' | foreach {
    Get-ChildItem -Path 'Cert:\LocalMachine\My' | 
    Select-Object -Property Issuer, Subject
    @{Label = 'ServerName';Expression = {$env:COMPUTERNAME}}
    @{Label='Expires In (Days)';Expression = {($_.NotAfter - (Get-Date)).Days}}
}`

Comment: When i tried the above script which you suggested for the Expiry In days one, i got the output as below, but i didnt get the exact count of the days.
**Key   : Expression
Value : $env:COMPUTERNAME
Name  : Expression**

Comment: I used the below code
`$threshold = 300   #Number of days to look for expiring certificates 
 
$deadline = (Get-Date).AddDays($threshold)   #Set deadline date 


Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'IN-LINGARCR-1', 'USTR-ERL2-2696' { 
    Get-ChildItem -Path 'Cert:\LocalMachine\My' | 
    Select-Object -Property Issuer, Subject 
    @{Label = 'ServerName';Expression = {$env:COMPUTERNAME}}, 
    @{Label='Expires In (Days)';Expression = {$_.notafter -le (get-date).AddDays($threshold)}} 
}`

Comment: Thanks for the help, i got the exact output like how i expected.
`Issuer            : CN
Subject           : CN
NotAfter          : 5/14/2023 5:30:00 AM
ServerName        : AAA
Expires In (Days) : 1207
PSComputerName    : AAA
RunspaceId        : 1`

Comment: In the select object i need the server name as well, but i am not sure like how to get the server name in the final output.
`Server            : 
Issuer            : CN
Subject           : CN
NotAfter          : 5/14/2023 5:30:00 AM
Expires In (Days) : 1207
PSComputerName    : BBB
RunspaceId        : f`

Comment: What server name? This PSComputerName property shows the server name as does the $env:ComputernName calculated property, as per the output I show above. Again, I am running this code in one of my labs and the data property vaules are correct from my runs. Are you saying the issue CA server name?

Comment: The script is good, i am asking like how can i get the server name/PSCOmputername at the first line before the Issuer

Comment: Just change the order of the select. Put the properties in the order you want them to come out. You cannot control when the default added property PSComputerName shows up in the default output.  Well, I've not really tried as I've found no need to do so. Yet, I did just try, and nope, meaning no default way of doing it. You can put that $env:ComputerName first, but that means you'd have the name twice, no matter what. Otherwise, you need to use a PSCustomObject or hash table to declare the layout you want.